# How to find the largest attribute value in a XML file?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am trying to create a small program that is able to print out the largest value of a attribute in an XML file. I have wrote the following code:

```
public class GetMaxLog {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = (Document)builder.parse("FILE");

    XPathFactory xpathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xpathfactory.newXPath();

    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//PasswordVault/User[@id = 1]//Log[not(@LOG < ../Log/@LOG)]/LOG/text()");

    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;     

  //returns the element at tag value 0 thus only the first set of data    
    System.out.println(nodes.item(0).getNodeValue());

}
```

}

And the XML file looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PasswordVault>
  <User id="1">
    <Log LOG="1">
      <AccountType>afsdgsd</AccountType>
      <Username>asdas</Username>
      <Password>dsgsdg</Password>
      <E-mail>aadfaf</E-mail>
    </Log>
    <Log LOG="10">
      <AccountType>afsdgsd</AccountType>
      <Username>asdas</Username>
      <Password>dsgsdg</Password>
      <E-mail>aadfaf</E-mail>
    </Log>
  </User>
</PasswordVault>
```

There is a NullPointerException error when i run the program. I am trying to find the largest LOG value and then print it out.I think that my query within Xpath is incorrect .Could anyone help me fix this query and the NullPointerException error also.

Comment: the @ didnt do anything, the error still occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### XPath 2.0

This XPath,

```
//Log[@LOG = max(//Log/@LOG)]
```

will select the `Log` elements with the maximum `@LOG` attribute value.

### XPath 1.0

This XPath,

```
//Log[not(../Log/@LOG > @LOG)]
```

will select the `Log` elements with the maximum `@LOG` attribute value.

Comment: `//Log[not(@LOG < ../Log/@LOG)]` ?

Comment: I keep getting NullPointerException with the system out line

Comment: @splash58: I like that idea for XPath 1.0 better. Answer updated. Thanks!

Comment: @splash58 thanks, it works